# Django: What's the fastest way to order a QuerySet based on the count of a related field?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I've got an `Item` model in my Django app with a ManyToMany field that's handled through an intermediate Favorite model. Here are simplified versions of the models in question:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

I'm trying to get a list of items ordered by the number of favorites. The query below works, however there are thousands of records in the Item table, and the query is taking up to a couple of minutes to complete.

```
items = Item.objects.annotate(num_favorites=Count('favorite')).order_by('-num_favorites')
```

Not sure if this is relevant to any potential answers, but I'm paginating the results using Django's built-in Pagintor:

```
paginator = Paginator(items, 100)
```

I know I can add a `favorites` field to my Item model and increment that every time an item is favorited, but I'm wondering if there's another cleaner, more efficient way to retrieve this data in a reasonable time.

Below is the output of the MySQL `EXPLAIN` function:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appname_item       | ALL  | NULL                        | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL                          |  566 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appname_favorite   | ref  | appname_favorite_67b70d25   | appname_favorite_67b70d25   | 4       | appname.appname_item.id       |    1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when ever you try to use order_by clause whose index is not defined, try to defined index on it, it makes the ordering process way faster, in you case index on 'num_favorites' is what you need to speed up the query execution time. also the technique which you are using is fine there is nothing bad in it.

please see the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008249/django-view-response-time-issues) which was asked by me on same issue, and `saverio` gave an excellent answer to tackle the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @Aamir, I +1'd a while ago but have only now had a chance to look into this. I looked through the answer to your question, but am not sure how to apply it to the problem I'm having. The MySQL docs on this seem pretty sparse. I've added the output of EXPLAIN to my question above, do you think you can help me figure out what it means and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That is already the best way. If it's slow, the problem is probably with your database - specifically, you don't have the right indexes for that query so the db is having to do too much sorting.

The Django debug toolbar is great for diagnosing this sort of thing - it will show you how long each query is taking, and allow you to run the db's EXPLAIN function on each one. The MySQL docs will tell you what the output from EXPLAIN means. However, after that it's up to you to optimise the db.

Comment: thanks @Daniel. I +1'd a while ago but have only now had a chance to look into this. I ran EXPLAIN and can see from the output that the query is not correctly executing, but have no clue how to fix it. I've read through the MySQL docs on EXPLAIN but they're not very helpful at all (I've read and re-read this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html and everything it refers to but it wasn't much help). I've added the output of EXPLAIN to my question, do you think you can help me decipher it? Thanks!